# Create unique Form input ID's and input name's in while loop

Tags: php, forms, input, foreach, while-loop

I have a table being built and populated by a while loop. the while loop is fetching and displaying results from a mysql database.

As per the below code, there is a checkbox on each line, value equal to a unique identifier `loadnumber`.

the next column is a input box with name and id of `correctedweight`. again the value of this is predefined by the MySQL data value. the next column is a select box named `correctedtrailer` and again the selected value is equal to the database result.

My sql query result has many lines in so my  table is several lines deep. What I am wanting to do, is allow the user to check the checkbox `checkbox[]`, change the values of `correctedweight` and    `correctedtrailer` on the same row and then submit the form. the problem is that if I have several rows, the names of all my `correctedweight` and `correctedtrailer` are all the same so I cant differentiate between them.

```
<? while($row = $loads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<tr>        
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="correctedweight" id="correctedweight" value="<? echo $row['weight']; ?>" class="inputsmall"></td>
    <td><SELECT name="correctedtrailer" id="correctedtrailer"  class="selectnarrow"> 
    <OPTION value="<? echo $row['trailer']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['trailer']; ?></option>
    <option>
    <?=$optionstrailer?> 
    </option>
    </SELECT> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

to fix this, can I append the loadnumber to the name and id of each input field?

`<input type="text" name="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['weight']; ?>" class="inputsmall">`

This will then give each input of my form a unique name. next question is how do I call this name for the selected rows? the `checkbox[]` array will contain the load number so in my `foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){` statement, how do I get the value of  `correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>`? is it $_POST['correctedweight.$checkbox'] or how does it work?

additionally is this the best way of doing this?

help appreciated as always. Thanks

image of my form, input and select fields prepopulated with MySQL data. want the ability to check and edit several of the table rows at once but need a unique identifier as table built with `while` loop. thanks again.
[image]

Comment: try `$correctedweight{$checkbox}`

Comment: Thanks DoSparKot, is this best practice and the best way to do it?

Comment: access the indeces via

`$_POST["correctedweight.$checkbox"]`
or

`$_POST['correctedweight'.$checkbox]`
and not `$_POST['correctedweight.$checkbox']` ..

because the variables inside single quoted string will not get parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what I can see you are looping through database entries. I would suggest using your load number as an identifier in all your fields, then looping through it in the post you can append it like you did above.

Something like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>]" id="checkbox[<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>]" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="correctedweight_<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedweight_<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['weight']; ?>" class="inputsmall"></td>
<td><SELECT name="correctedtrailer_<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedtrailer_<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
    <option value="<? echo $row['trailer']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['trailer']; ?></option>
    <option><?=$optionstrailer?></option>
</SELECT>
```

Getting the information per checkbox in the post:

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
    $correctedweight = $_POST['correctedweight_$checkbox'];
    $correctedtrailer = $_POST['correctedtrailer_$checkbox'];
}
```

Remember you will only get checkboxes that was checked if I remember correct :)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Werner, does the checkbox name not need to remain checkbox[] else each selected checkbox will belong to a separate array?

Comment: You can to that, but this way the key of your array will be the loadnumber instead of the default 0,1,2,3.. This helps if you need the key as well :)