# How to submit and handle values from a form inside a table

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update, html-table

I have a HTML table with an arbitrary amount of rows, each with 4 columns. And the idea is to let the user edit any of these rows and then save the result. These changes should then be saved to a database. But I have several problems.

I have found some posts on stackoverflow indicating on how you should approach this, but none perfectly useful in my case. This is how it looks when the user is editing my table (although I only have one row now, there can be several).

[image: my table]

And of course there's a submit button, that takes my to a php file named something like "handle_edit.php".

Now [another post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890509/create-unique-form-input-ids-and-input-names-in-while-loop) about this subject has indicated that I should use some kind of foreach-loop to edit one row in the SQL table per row in my HTML table. My version of this loop in "handle_edit.php" looks like this right now:

```
foreach( $_POST['appearances'] as $appearances ) {
    $goals = $_POST['goals'];
    $assists = $_POST['assists'];
    $name = ??????? //How to I do this?

    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE players
                            SET appearances=$appearances, goals=$goals, assists=$assists
                            WHERE name=$name");
}
```

First of all. The `foreach` loop needs to contain an array expression, and the compiler tells me that's not the case right now. But I have no idea on how to count the amount of rows. In the thread I linked above they are doing something similar to this, but I don't think I fully understand what they are doing since my `foreach` loop isn't working.

Secondly, since the name column in the table isn't an input field, I don't know how to send it to this page with the rest of the information. I need to do it somehow, since I want to determine which row to edit based on the name provided. Each of the players in this SQL table has an unique player id, could I use that somehow?

Am I maybe approaching this the wrong way? Is there a more viable solution?

Please tell me if you need any additional code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you are approaching wrong way.You need to learn 1.hidden input fields 2.Database primary keys 3.sql injection and may be more..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the name variable.
you need to add `<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<*YOUR WAY OF GETTING THE NAME*>'/>` to your form. if you do so, you can get the value of the name in your foreach loop with `$_POST['name']`. For more info on how to make a form for php look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Secondly, the sql string u use is wrong. You cant input the variable names within a string. I suggest declaring the sql string first like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE players SET appearances=" . $appearances . ", goals=" . $goals . ", assists=" . $assists . " WHERE name=". $name;
```

Then make the connection and execute the query like so:

```
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

for the foreach problem, i suggest debugging using the `var_dump()` method and see if you really get an array back with `$_POST['appearances']`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using a hidden field solved the second issue, of course. Thanks!

And `var_dump()` tells me that `$_POST['appearances']` does indeed not contain an array, which I kind of suspected. The only reason I tried doing it like this is because they used it in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890509/create-unique-form-input-ids-and-input-names-in-while-loop. But I guess a checkbox works different.

So if that doesn't give me the number of rows, how can I get it? And how do I get all of the different values on the different rows since `$_POST[value]` only seems to give me the last row?

Comment: Solved my first problem by adding array brackets ([]) to the names of my input fields. E.g. writing `name="appearances[]"`instead of `name="appearances"` for my appearances input field. This turns `$_POST['appearances']` into an array containing the value from each row. Then I can just access these different values doing by something like `$appearances = $_POST['appearances']` and e.g get the value from index 0 by doing `$appearances[0]`. Since Nick answered one question and I'm answering the second one myself, should I just mark Nick's answer as the answer or post this comment as an answer?

Comment: you can indeed mark it as anwer. Since you posted your answer in the comments to my answer, people with the same problem will read it as well.